# weblogic admin server remains down | RAM issue

Tags: weblogic, ram, weblogic11g, infrastructure

What are the benefits/justification of keeping weblogic admin server up?

our weblogic admin server has major multiple production application agents.The total memory available in the server is 4 GB. But, It is utilizing more than 4 GB in peak utilization time. Due to memory crunch we get high CPU utilization alerts from the server so we bring down the services in admin server. if we do not bring down the services it may lead to process will be Hang and reboot the server.
For permanent fix, we need to increase the memory. What justifications can I give to client to increase the RAM and keep the server running always?

Answer (score 0):

The admin server controls the domain configuration so you will need it running to install applications or change other settings. The managed servers can run without the admin server active, but these servers will run using a cached configuration.

Typically the admin server does not require as much memory as the managed servers so you can probably tune the memory settings down for the admin server leaving more memory available for the managed servers.